# How do I make popover views not ignore the device's size class?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have a storyboard that I have made using Interface Builder. I have modified it for the "Regular Width | Regular Height" size class. When displayed normally (taking up the entire screen), the size class modifications are acknowledged, and it does look different on the appropriate devices.

However, when displayed as a popover view (the segue used to present it is of type "Present as Popover"), the size class modifications are ignored. No matter the device, the popover view is displayed using the default "Any" size class.

I'm looking for a way to force the size class of the device to be acknowledged, and display the storyboard with the appropriate changes. I'm not using the default popover view size; the size is different on every device.

One last thing to note is that I have overridden a function and added a new one to the view that displays the popover view, in order to ensure that the popover view is displayed as a popover on an iPhone, as opposed to a full view:

```
//Forces the settings view controller to be displayed as a popover on an iPhone
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.destinationViewController as? SettingsViewController != nil {
        if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController! {
            controller.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
            controller.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width/2, height: view.frame.size.height/3)
        }
    }
}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    // Return no adaptive presentation style, use default presentation behaviour
    return .None
}
```

Comment: Popovers have a different size class from the controller that presents the popover. In particular the width will become compact. A suggestion is to set the constraints for Regular Height | Any Width if you want the popovers to show the changes.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel If I use the "Regular Height | Any Width" size class, the change seems to happen for all devices. Xcode says that the "Regular Height | Compact Width" class includes all iPhones in portrait mode. I only want the changes to happen for "Regular Height | Regular Width" devices, which I believe is only the iPad.

Comment: Yes, apologies, you are correct. An option might be to try and override traitCollection in your controller and return your own if you can detect you are in a popover.